# array elements how to check if one element is only 1 bigger than the other

Tags: java, arrays

i want to check if one element is 1 higher than the other, like

anArray[i] > anArray[i+1]

except i want it to only check if anArray[i] is only 1 bigger than anArray[i+1]

Answer (score 0):

So, in other words you want to know if i-th element is equal to i+1-th element + 1

```
anArray[i] == anArray[i+1]+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
anArray[i] == anArray[i+1] + 1;
```

Comment: What's with the triple equals?

Comment: thought it said javascript heh my bad.